# Issue installing mysql server on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mysql, linux, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I trying to install mysql server on ubuntu 16.04, but when I tried to execute the command: sudo mysql_secure_installation. I am getting the error message:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

Just tried:

`sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client`

This is my sql version installed: (`mysql --version`):

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.12, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine
>   wrapper

It looks like the mysql was installed on my machine.

The fist time I installed mysql server, the installer ask me for the user root password, but the second time, the installer don't ask me for this credentials, and then if I put the command: `mysql_secure_installation`, I am getting the same issue:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).

Also I tried to install alone the mysql server without the client, and the issue is the same. I tried to `remove.purge` and reinstall mysql, but I wasn't able to get working mysql, I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Is the mysql server running? Try `sudo service mysql restart`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the socket locked file :

```
sudo rm /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

And start mysql service :

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

Comment: Hello,  The file doesn't exist, and I cannot find any references on how to build my own sock file. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mysql service is not running on your linux machine. You can check the whether the service is running or not using `systemctl`

```
systemctl status mysql
```

If the service is not running you can start the service using `systemctl`

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

But this will start the service for the current session only. If you reboot the machine you have to again start the `mysql` server. To auto start the service on reboot execute

```
sudo systemctl enable mysql
```

Comment: I put the command :systemctl status mysql, and I got the issue
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since lun 2016-07-25 20:30:40 COT
  Process: 928 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exite
: Failed to start MySQL Communi
j: mysql.service: Unit entered f
]: mysql.service: Failed with re
: mysql.service: Service hold-o
: Stopped MySQL Community Serve
: mysql.service: Start request 
 Failed to start MySQL Communi
lines 1-12/12 END

Comment: Can you try running the command `journalctl -u mysql` and provide the log output ? Paste the log on `gist` or any other similar service and provide the link to the log.