# Cannot install mysql-server 5.7 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Please note that I am unable to install mysql-server on Ubuntu.  This is what I'm seeing.

```
user@MyServer:~/Install$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-client
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 10.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 110 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-client all 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [10.1 kB]
Fetched 10.1 kB in 0s (32.6 kB/s)       
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'apache2-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 365868 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client_5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1524: Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up mysql-client (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So far I have been researching these links but haven't found anything helpful.

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-solve-error-1524-hy000-plugin-unix_socket-is-not-loaded-mysql-error-on-debian-ubuntu/
[Issues on reinstalling MySQL 5.7 server on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241494/issues-on-reinstalling-mysql-5-7-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)
[Issue installing mysql server on ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537781/issue-installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

Please note that in the end I settled with using MariaDB because it installs and uninstalls without a problem on Ubuntu 16.04 but when I try to install and uninstall MySQL I end up getting a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you are installing MySQL over what was formerly a MariaDB installation.

Installs of this form aren't supported. Recommend dumping data from the MariaDB (using mariadb running on the data directory) (mysqldump) and manually porting the mysql.* table contents (create user and grants(, backup and move the /var/lib/mysql data directory, and retry the installation.

Alternately continue to use MariaDB.

Comment: Okay I did this command but it still doesn't let me install mysql-server:  "$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mariadb-server"  Is there a way I can remove MariaDB and just install mysql-server?  I don't care about any of the data in MariaDB.

Comment: `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql`. The extra work in mysql's package is because the datadir has contents.

Comment: Also I did this command to ensure all MariaDB databases were removed: "$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mariadb\*"

Comment: Correction, the full command is sudo apt remove --purge mariadb\\*